# getting all values python+selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

there was a problem getting values. I'm new to working with Python + selenium. I need to get the items that are indicated by the green arrow (44. 1443, 363)

[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWPQw.jpg)

and list them out. I try to do this:

```
likes=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/b')
for spisok in likes:
print(spisok.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class named 'post-act' is unique and the below XPath is identifying the values that you want :

> //div[@class='post-act']//div/b

Then you can try like below :

```
sleep(3)
all = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='post-act']//div/b")
for i in all:
    print i.text
```

Comment: if use //div[@class='post-act']//div/b i get 2  values (http://joxi.ru/DrljNJ3tvp0O52)
and if i use class name col-md-6 col-lg-6 (likes=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-md-6 col-lg-6']//div/b"))
 (http://joxi.ru/vAWj4Qot1JqQD2)  i get nothing without error

Comment: Can you post the picture of all three values expanded? And try to give some delay before locating the elements

Comment: 1) http://joxi.ru/gmvK3QNCL9vVy2
2) http://joxi.ru/VrwZ35JCON8QOA
3) http://joxi.ru/n2Yjn6otoqZ97A
i set time.sleep(5) and driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Comment: Are you able to identify manually by inspecting this `//div[@class='post-act']//div/b` xpath? Is it highlighting `<b>` tags?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean)
 http://joxi.ru/Rmz3edMH01Rz92

Comment: Do control + f in that source page and try to find out `//div[@class='post-act']//div/b` xpath and lets see how many matches are you getting?

Comment: Otherwise, can you share the URL which you are trying to find out if possible so that I can try the correct locator

Comment: find 40 (http://joxi.ru/Rmz3edMH01Rx92) but need only 20 (http://joxi.ru/gmvK3QNCL9vgy2)

Comment: this is a closed service(

Comment: Ok, it is showing multiple matches because the XPath is not unique. Which 20 you want to print? Can you share some above html code so that we can find some unique locator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get specific node value try like this.

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath(“(//div[@class=‘post-act’]//div/b)[n]”)

print(element.text)
```

Here n=1...n depends on which node data you are fetching your case n should be 1.Try this and let me know if this work.

Comment: Thanks @Ali I have done this via phone and unable to format the content.